# index like parcolums delim

Tags: indexing, parcolumns, makeindex

The printed index in LaTeX provides by default at first `item`, some indent and the `page number`. The `.idx-file`looks like

```
\begin{theindex}

\item{Test}\hspace{0.2cm}1
...
\end{theindex}
```

For `\hspace{0.2cm}` you can use `dotfill`or `vfill` in the `.ist-file`.

`delim_0 "\\vfill"`

If you use `\hspace`, all pagenumbers are written next to `item` filling up the line to the right and for example the next line and so on.

If you use `\vfill`or `\dotfill`, between `\item` and the pagenumbers there is space (spatium) or dots. If there are two pagenumbers, the numbers are written from the right filling up the space to the left.

`\item{Test}\hfill 1,2,3`

That is not what I need!

I need at the leftmargin `\item` and in each and every case the pagenumbers in the middle of the whole column. Take a look [here](https://www.yumpu.com/de/document/view/43769510/stellenregister-septuaginta-deutsch):

[image]

In the US it's maybe not common, but in Germany it is.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: (I also removed you "thanks". There is nothing personnal here, it is just [not the habit](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2809/64454) on this site.)

Comment: your question doesn't seem very clear, what have you tried, what error did you get?  You can set the `delim_0`, `delim_1` etc strings to be any sequence of TeX commands and define those commands in any way. Where do you see any documentation about being restricted to the tree commands you mention?